# WebDriverError: element click intercepted: Other element would receive the click - detection

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to detect if an element is **clickable** before attempting to click it. In my specific use case the element is hidden by another element on top of it during processing and when done, the overlay is removed and the element can be clicked. Unfortunately the condition `elementIsVisible` does not consider an element to be hidden by another element nor does the method `WebElement.isDisplayed` of an element.

```js
// find an element that is hidden behind some overlay
const hiddenElement = await driver.findElement(By.id('hiddenElement'));

// wait for element returns the "hidden" element
const await visibleElement = driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(hiddenElement));

// "isDisplayed" reports the "hidden" element as visible
const visible = await hiddenElement.isDisplayed();
```

I could clearly use the overlay element to detect if the element is hidden but this would have to be customized for each different type of overlay and I'm actually looking for a more generic way to detect if an element is actually **clickable**.

Comment: How about condition `elementToBeClickable`?

Comment: Had same experience. This is because at the moment there are some other elements appear. Like Fade in message or etc. Solution is wait until page is stable. then perform your function. Note ElementToBeClickable may also not work

Comment: @Fenio I'm not aware of any condition `elementToBeClickable` in the webdriver api for javascript?

Comment: @doberkofler Right, you look for JS solution and there is no such solution. Basically, this condition checks if the element is `visible` and `enabled`. It won't help you case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did actually find a solution that works as expected by myself that can be distilled to the following:

A function `isElementClickable` that is responsible for checking if an element is clickable:

```js
function isElementClickable(element) {
    const SCRIPT = `
    const element = arguments[0];

    // is element visible by styles
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    if (!(styles.visibility !== 'hidden' && styles.display !== 'none')) {
        return false;
    }

    // is the element behind another element
    const boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // adjust coordinates to get more accurate results
    const left = boundingRect.left + 1;
    const right = boundingRect.right - 1;
    const top = boundingRect.top + 1;
    const bottom = boundingRect.bottom - 1;

    if (document.elementFromPoint(left, top) !== element ||
        document.elementFromPoint(right, top) !== element ||
        document.elementFromPoint(left, bottom) !== element ||
        document.elementFromPoint(right, bottom) !== element) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
    `;

    return element.getDriver().executeScript(SCRIPT, element);
}
```

A function 'elementIsClickableCondition' that can be used as a replacement condition instead of `webdriver.until.elementIsVisible`:

```js
function elementIsClickableCondition(locator) {
    return new webdriver.WebElementCondition('until element is visible', async function (driver) {
        try {
            // find the element(s)
            const elements = await driver.findElements(locator);
            if (elements.length > 1) {
                throw new Error(`elementIsClickableCondition: the locator "${locator.toString()} identifies "${elements.length} instead of 1 element`);
            } else if (elements.length < 1) {
                return null;
            }

            const element = elements[0];

            // basic check if the element is visible using the build-in functionality
            if (!await element.isDisplayed()) {
                return null;
            }

            // really check if the element is visible
            const visible = await isElementClickable(element);

            return visible ? element : null;
        } catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof webdriver.error.StaleElementReferenceError) {
                return null;
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        }
    });
}
```